# Dictionary Initializers in pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, series

```
import pandas as pd
grades = pd.Series({'Wally': 87, 'Eva': 100, 'Sam': 94},index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(grades)
```

output:

```
a   NaN       
b   NaN       
c   NaN 
dtype: float64
```

why this output? I searched in diffrent site but I don't understand this output, when use index attribute in dictionary initializer. Please explain for me.

Comment: You probably want `pd.Dataframe()`.

Comment: What is your expected output? For example, if you run the code without passing in your `index=` argument, is that what you expect? Or do you expect each key:value pair to be a row in the pandas series? Do you expect a dataframe with multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

read `pd.Series` document
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

index : array-like or Index (1d) 
Values must be hashable and have the same length as data. Non-unique index values are allowed. Will default to RangeIndex (0, 1, 2, …, n) if not provided. **If data is dict-like** and index is None, then the keys in the data are used as the index. **If the index is not None, the resulting Series is reindexed with the index values.**